# Java determine type of class

Tags: java

Is there any mechanism in `java` to determine in runtime if given `class` signature is `interface` or `class` or is this info erased by compiler?
I mean:

```
class Foo {
}
interface Bar{
}
```

is `Foo.class` and `Bar.class` class or interface?

Comment: Just was interested. No particular reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `isInterface()` on the `Class` object. From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInterface%28%29)

```
public boolean isInterface()

Determines if the specified Class object represents an interface type.

Returns:
    true if this object represents an interface; false otherwise.
```

Comment: Well, I should have investigated before asking "I wonder" question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class gives a method [isInterface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInterface()) to determine whether the object is an interface. Here is the signature:

> public boolean isInterface()
>
> Determines if the specified Class object
> represents an interface type.
>
> Returns: true if this object represents
> an interface; false otherwise.

Comment: please leave a comment when u leave a down vote. I want to learn from my mistakes.